# динамическое движение кнопок

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

[ссылка на проект](https://github.com/x0VERLORDx/squears.git)

после вынесения стилей из html в отдельный css файл кнопки взбесились и не хотят останавливаться. До изменений функция move работала исправно

```
(function move () {
    const delay = 2;
    let i = 0;
    startTimer = function () {
        let left = delColBtn.offsetLeft;
        //console.log(i);
        i = left + 1;
        if (i < colIndex * 54 + 60) {
            setTimeout(startTimer,delay);
            //console.log(colIndex);
            delColBtn.style.left = left + 1 + 'px';

        }

        else if (i > 64 && i > colIndex * 54 + 60){
            setTimeout(startTimer,delay);
            delColBtn.style.left = left - 1 + 'px'; 
        }
    }
    const timer = setTimeout(startTimer,delay);
}) ();
```

Comment: А мы должны догадаться в чем проблема?

Comment: Вы пробовали работать со стилями но при этом старый скрипт?

Comment: стили были просто вынесены в отдельный файл. После чего всё работало кроме функций передвижения кнопок

Comment: Вы поменяли переменные с глобальных на локальные.  Посмотрите логи с равните.

Comment: Обернул код в IIFE. На сколько я  знаю внутри этой функции переменные должны быть доступны. Ошибка возникла ещё до этого.

Comment: Я не могу понять что двигает этой кнопкой. Вывод счетчика который находиться в ифе останавливается в какой то момент а кнопка нет

Comment: Поставьте логи и смотрите за ними. Любое место где может быть изменена кнопка. Пронумеруйте логи console.log(1, ...)

Answer (score 0):

в стилях была изменена позиция кнопок с position:absolute;  на relative